# #1194 - table 'user' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have problems getting into Mysql on phpmyadmin

(mysqli_real_connect()(HY000/1130)Host 'localhost'is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server )

I have found out its a crashed file in mysql called "user'
All the info I have read says to fix a crashed table use the dropdown menu 'With Selcted' . My 'With Selected' is not a dropdown (XAMPP Version: 7.3.7 , Control Panel Version: 3.2.4 ). It is in italic.
Is there a shell command that I can use.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just posted my question and I got a comment answer from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63132667) on Stack Overflow:

> First try to run the following command: mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair --check --all-databases – Philip Petrov [1 hour ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63132667/mysqli-real-connecthy000-1130host-localhostis-not-allowed-to-connect-to-th#comment111670078_63132667)

Comment: that works only , if you can still log in, else you can try to reset the root password

Answer (score 0):

Switch from Engine=MyISAM to Engine=InnoDB.